# How to define IF clause within WHERE condition in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying a simple if statement within where condition in SQL. I don't want `CASE` statement since it is very simple.

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetStatus]
    @siteId INT,


    ........
    FROM sites
    WHERE StartDate = @reportMonth
      AND..
      AND ...
      AND IF(@siteId > 0) sites.SiteId = @siteId 
    ........
```

I would like to define simple as above.

My `siteId` parameter can be 0 or greater than that, if user passes a integer value. I want to omit my AND condition if `siteId` parameter is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You normally handle this with boolean logic within your SQL. So you can just write:

```
WHERE  StartDate = @reportMonth
AND..
AND ...
AND (@siteId <=0 OR  sites.SiteId = @siteId)
```

So if `@siteId` is not greater than 0 it ignores the rest of the `OR` clause, but if it is, then it evaluates your `sites.SiteId` clause. Normally for a stored proc I'd set default value to null and check for nullness:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetStatus]

@siteId INT = NULL,
........
from sites;
 WHERE  StartDate = @reportMonth
AND..
AND ...
AND (@siteId IS NULL OR  sites.SiteId = @siteId)
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but for completeness I would also mention the [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) expression.

Comment: The question specifically stated that they were aware of the `case` statement but wanted an alternative.

Comment: Yeah, missed that somehow

Answer (score 1):

I would rather suggest

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetStatus]
    @siteId INT,


    ........
    FROM sites
    WHERE StartDate = @reportMonth
      AND..
      AND ...
      AND 
sites.SiteId = case when @siteId > 0 then @siteId else sites.SiteId end
```